# learning about git clone and how

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, git, reactjs

I am new to the whole git thing. I have a fresh computer with nothing installed, if I clone a program from git that has a front end and back end and then do an npm install will it download all the necessary files I need automatically? such as react express and others.

Comment: Depends on the package.json located in your project.

Comment: Yes is the simple answer. Usually the README.md file will have more information about what  you need to do to get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will install all the modules which are listed in package.json. You need to navigate to the project directory and then execute this command: npm install